Movie about two girls who start robbing banks and giving the money to the needy
I think this movie was released around 5 to 6 years ago.
In this movie, a bank agree a loan deal with a farmer - if the farmer is unable to pay back his loan, then the bank only has to give one dollar and get his all property and farming land..
Later, a villager girl and a modern girl plan to rob a bank. To do that they take training from an expert robber (who also may be a fighting expert).
Following this, they start to rob different banks with planning and fighting. They make so many robberies in many banks, and use the money they rob to provide food and to look after the poor people of the village.  

I think the year is a bit off. This sounds like Bandidas from 2006.

yeh, walt It is bandidas.. I forget specific year of that movies release..

Can it be be Bandidas that you are referring to?
From Wikipedia -

Set in Mexico during the 1850s, the film tells the story of Sara
  Sandoval (Salma Hayek) and María Álvarez (Penélope Cruz). María is an
  uneducated, poor farm-girl whose caring father is being forced off his
  land by a cruel U.S. land baron, named Tyler Jackson (Dwight Yoakam).
  Sara is the highly educated, wealthy daughter of the arrogant owner of
  the nearby properties, and has recently returned from Europe where she
  attended numerous grade schools and colleges in England, Spain, and
  France for several years. In one fell swoop, both María's and Sara's
  fathers fall under attack by the baron, (Sara's father is killed,
  María's is shot but survives) giving him free rein in the nearby
  territories. As an act of revenge, María and Sara team up to become
  bank robbers, stealing and giving back to the poor Mexicans who had
  lost their lands.


movie name: Bandidas
In turn-of-the-century Mexico, two very different women become a bank-robbing duo in an effort to combat a ruthless enforcer terrorizing their town.
Star girl:  Penélope Cruz,Salma Hayek
source link: wikipedia, imdb
